# Implementing a simple MPC

Tags: control

I am trying to teach myself how an MPC works by implementing one from scratch.

I found a great resource that explains how an MPC works: [https://cse.sc.edu/~gatzke/cache/npc-Chapter5-scan.pdf](https://cse.sc.edu/%7Egatzke/cache/npc-Chapter5-scan.pdf)

There are 3 variables (referring to the first MPC example in the pdf file)

- x1, x2, and u

The objective of the MPC is to keep x2 at 1.0 by manipulating u.

You have the derivatives of x1 and x2 (wrt time I think?) in eq 5.5 and 5.6
You also have the objective function in eq 5.7

And the initial condition is x1=2.9997 and x2=1.11697

Can someone walk me through every step of the calculation in getting the next control input u?

Also, I know that you need to minimize the objective function over the look-ahead duration. Is there a C++ library that can do the minimization (even though I said I want to implement the MPC from scratch, I don't want to implement the minimization algorithm myself).